# How do we know what time/what website is a MEW wallet created?

Tags: json-rpc, private-key

I lost Private Key + JSON file to open my myEtherwallet. But is there anybody knowing somehow to find:

- What time is a MEW wallet created?
- what website that has created an Ethereum wallet? (This is because I am not sure I had created this MEW from the www.myetherwallet.com.

Many thanks to You all!

Quiet Mind.

Answer (score 0):

If you used a legit website to create this wallet the following, to the best of my knowledge, will be impossible to retrieve:

- Creation date & Time
- Who created the file

As any legit website would generate the wallet file client side and not log or save this information.

I created a new JSON file representing a new throwaway wallet from MEW and nothing in that file would tell me that MEW generated it.

All addresses on Ethereum already exist - so there's no creation date associated with wallets on the EVM.

Comment: Thank MSwezey anyway. Can we hack my MEW wallet as I still keep the password ?

Comment: You used the website correct? Not the Chrome Extension? 

The password alone will do nothing as you need the encrypted data inside JSON file for the password to be of use.